# How to identify the column index using column header dynamically c#

Tags: c#

Language: C#

I have an excel stored in the local path.
I want to open the excel and update the value for a column say OrderID. But the placement of OrderID column may vary.
I want to identify the column index by specifying the name of the column(Column Header).
Is this possible to do?

So far i have written only the below code,

```
*string folderPath = @"C:\Test";

string file = folderPath + @"\OrderData.xlsx";

using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(file)))
{
  ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Orders");
  int excelRowNumber = 4;  //This is the row i have to make the update

  string columnName = "OrderID";
  int columnIndex = ? //Need help in identifying the columnIndex dynamically based on columnName

  worksheet.Cells[excelRowNumber, columnIndex].Value = "ABCD";

  excel.Save();
}*
```

Comment: How can you identify what column in excel file contains OrderID? Do it have a header row with column names?

Comment: Hi Ivan,

This is the excel format
                         A                                 B
Row 1              OrderId                      Customer
Row 2              (Need to fill this)        xyz

I have to find that the column index of OrderId is 1 and fill the value in cell[2,1]

Comment: Are you using EPPlus? Can you provide content of for example 5-7 rows with header row to work with. Give it like a simple markdown table.